# Displaying a string of one of the players in a Photon Room (4 players) when a condition is met

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, photon

Playerprefs has a way of setting and getting players' info such as string, int, etc.

I am using photon to set and get each player's string but it only captures one local player! The string which each player enters should, later on, be displayed to all other Players only if a condition is met (bool).

Does Playerprefs actually store each player's information and can it actually be retrieved (Every player)?

For example:
When it's your turn to play then let's say a bool is set to true then display your string to all other players.
So a game over should be activated and prevent the game from continuing!

Am I doing this through the following scripts below: Your suggestion or correction would really mean a lot. I have been stuck for a while.

My first Script (Input string):

```
[SerializeField]
WordInfo wordInfo;

void Update()
{
    wordInfo.word = StringWord;
}

public void GetString()
{
    StringWord = PlayerPrefs.GetString("word", "no word");
}
//use Onclick to set the string 
public void SetString()
{
    saveWord = InputWord.text;
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("word", saveWord);
}
```

My second Script (Retrieve the entered string to be read from another scene (static))

```
public class WordInfo: MonoBehaviour
{
public string word;
public static WordInfo wordInfo;

private void Awake()
{
    if (wordInfo == null)
    {
        wordInfo = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    else if(wordInfo != this)
    {
        Destroy(wordInfo.gameObject);
        wordInfo = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

My third script (Game script - different scene)

```
public string TheSavedWord;
private const string DISPLAY_MY_STRING_PLAYER = "{0} Your Word is displayed to others!";
private const string DISPLAY_OTHER_STRING_PLAYER = "{0}'s word has been Displayed!";
private const string MY_WORD = "{0} your word is: ";

private void Update()
{
    TheSavedWord = WordInfo.wordInfo.word;

}
 
public void ShowPlayerString()
{
 //a bool to check when to display the string
 //if i am active and the isShow is set to true then display a notification
 Player_Notification.text = string.Format(isShow && iAmActive ? DISPLAY_MY_STRING_PLAYER : DISPLAY_OTHER_STRING_PLAYER, activePlayer.NickName);
 
 //display the string 
 WordToDisplay.text = string.Format(isShow && iAmActive ? MY_WORD+ " " + TheSavedWord: MY_WORD + " " + TheSavedWord, activePlayer.NickName);

}
```

Comment: Player Prefs is local to the player setting the values.  If you need to transmit a value to all clients, you will need to use RPC or Player CustomProperties.

Comment: PlayerPrefs stores whatever you want **locally** .. it has nothing to do with Custom properties of Photon whatsoever ...

Comment: I am trying to use the custom properties but It's quite technical to me! I really know what I want but immediately I start typing I just get confused with calling the properties.

Comment: @derHugo your guidance would really mean a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked out fine. After multiple trials and understanding, I was able to get each player's string.

Here is the code:

```
[SerializeField]
WordInfo wordInfo;

void Update()
{
    wordInfo.word = saveWord;
}

//use Onclick to set the string 
public void SetString()
{
    saveWord = InputWord.text;

    var hash = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties;
    hash.Add("SaveWord", saveWord);
    PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(hash);

    if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient) return;

    Debug.Log(PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ToStringFull());
    
}
public override void OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate(Player targetPlayer, ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable changedProps)
{
    base.OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate(targetPlayer, changedProps);

    if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient) return;
    if (!changedProps.ContainsKey("SaveWord")) return;
}
```

Initially, I was using player prefs which was only calling locally to the player. So this was my previous code (The original code before improving it):

```
[SerializeField]
WordInfo wordInfo;

void Update()
{
    wordInfo.word = StringWord;
}

public void GetString()
{
    StringWord = PlayerPrefs.GetString("word", "no word");
}
//use Onclick to set the string 
public void SetString()
{
    saveWord = InputWord.text;
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("word", saveWord);
}
```

Comment: To help make this answer clearer, can you provide a summary of the difference between your original code and the code you've provided in the answer?

Comment: Just updated the summary of the original code @PeterGordon